# Duplicate file/symbol issue in Objective-C

Tags: ios, duplicates, cocoalumberjack

I am using 2 libraries which both need/using `cocoalumberjack`. One library is open source and other one is closed source. When I include both and try to compile, I get duplicate symbol/file issue. Just wondering how this can be fixed?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about static libraries?  If so do these static libraries also include the cocoalumberjack objects?

Comment: Going by the path that says "DerivedData", it looks as if you're building one of the "libraries" as source files in your project.  If that's true, I'd try building it into a static library and linking that.  Then the linker **should** only use symbols from it that don't exist elsewhere.  (Unless you're forcing it to load all symbols with a link flag.)